# React: sharing a variable between functions in a same component

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state, react-16

I have a function where I am supposed to pass file name so that it can reach next component but I have no idea how to achieve this in functional React. As of now I have a variable file which stores the filename returned from the API below

```
let file = "";
function submitForm(contentType, data, setResponse) {
    axios({
        url: `http://localhost:5000/uploadfile`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': contentType
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        setResponse(response.data)
        file = response.data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        setResponse("error");
    })
}
```

which I have to pass in here below in function handleClick

```
export default function Step2({fileName}) {

    function handleClick() {
        fileName = setFile(file);
        console.log(fileName);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
        window.location.replace('/step3?fileName='+fileName)
    }

...
```

I need to understand how this will work.

Comment: you just wanna pass `file = response.data` from submitForm into handleClick?

Comment: Yes passing the filename down from one to other function

Comment: try useState hook

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by having the function inside the component function and useState hook.